# Using Bash find to identify files whose folder contains a desired word

Tags: bash, file, shell, video, vlc

I have written a very simple bash program to find video files with a given name and play them in VLC.

This works well enough, but I can't seem to figure out how to cause the find command to also check the name of the containing folder.

This is a problem as I often watch series which are in descriptively named folders, but whose file names are often "episode 1", "episode 2", etc.

I can't simply search for the folders themselves as the folders might contain other files in formats that VLC cannot handle.

My current code appears as follows:

```
A=$(find -iname "*$partOfNameToFind*"  -exec echo -n '"{}" ' \;  | grep   -e mp4 -e flv -e wav -e wmv | sed -e 's/\.\///g' | tr '\n' ' ')

eval vlc --nointeract $A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-iwholename` might be the option you are looking for. While `-iname` only operates on the filename, `-iwholename` operates on... well... the whole name (path). ;-)

With some more "find spice" added, you might eventually turn up with:

```
find . -type f \
       -iwholename "*$partOfNameToFind*" \
       \( -name "*.mp4" \
       -o -name "*.flv" \
       -o -name "*.wav" \
       -o -name "*.wmv" \
       \) \
       -exec vlc --nointeract {} +
```

Note that the above will match `$partOfNameToFind` in *either* file *or* directory names.

`find ... -exec {}` correctly handles filenames whatsoever, including spaces, glob characters, newlines or whatnot. The trailing `+` gives multiple hits as one line of arguments; if your query matches *lots* of files (as in, a list longer than the shell can handle), this will be broken up in *multiple* invocations of `vlc`.

A trailing `\;` would instead give one invocation of `vlc --nointeract` per file found.

All that being said, I always found `man find` to be a *real* treasure trove. ;-)

Comment: Much safer to use `find ... -exec vlc --nointeract {} +`, as your approach will break if file names contain spaces or glob characters.

Comment: @TomFenech: The `printf` does enclose the filename in quotation marks, so spaces are safe. Yes, your approach is safer still (though anyone having glob characters in his filenames *deserves* any problems that might bring) -- but I wanted to stay *somewhat* close to the OP's original. Adding your variant to the answer.

Comment: @glennjackman: *sigh*... that's what you get for "quickly" answering a "simple" question in passing, going mostly with what you find in the OP's question and assuming that what he says "works", actually *works*...

Comment: The files downloaded from torrents often have `[]` in the filenames... e.g. `the.great.movie.[720p].mp4`... Sigh! I do tend to rename them after download, but if they are bulk-copied from someone, then this step is usually missed.